# What is the difference between $\tan(1)$ and $\tan(1^\circ)$?

Tags: trigonometry

This might seem pretty ease, but I've tried and I haven't got anything in my mind.

> What is the difference between $\tan(1)$ and $\tan(1^\circ)$?

Thank You!

Comment: There is a difference. Without a degree symbol, technically it is assumed to be radians. But then lazy math folks leave of the degree symbol for $tan30$ because nobody expects 30 radians.

Comment: @imranfat, What would be the value of tan 1 as compared to tan 1 degree.

Comment: @Amadeus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian see this,I hope it clears your doubt

Comment: @Amadeus $\tan(1radian)\approx 1.557407724$ whereas $\tan(1degree)\approx 0.017455064$. So the difference is approximately $1.557407724-0.017455064=1.53995266$. :) From: https://wolframalpha.com

Comment: Thank you @MichaelMorrow!!

Comment: As "%" is an abbreviation of "$\cdot\frac{1}{100}$" you might consider "${}^\circ$" as an abbreviation of "$\cdot\frac{\pi}{180}$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you don't see degree symbol hanging around the argument value then generally it is believed that argument value is angle in radians therefore

$\tan 1= tan\frac{180}{\pi}^{\circ}$.

In the comment you asked about value of $\tan 1= tan\frac{180}{\pi}^{\circ}$ as compared to  $\tan 1^{\circ}$, so the former will be greater than the latter due to increasing nature of $f(x)=\tan x$ in the interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: Gotcha thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I can't. Need 15 rep.

Comment: No problem. I'm happy that I could help you

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times, when unit is not written it is assumed to be radians. The symbol for radians is "c". Therefore, Tan(1) is assumed to be Tan(1 radians) $\approx$ 1.55740772465, where as Tan(1 degree) $\approx$ 0.01745506.
There are several other units like Minutes and Seconds, with different definitions in different systems. Those interested can have a look at points 1., 2., 3. and 9.
in chapter I from S. L. Loney Plane Trigo part-I. I have attached a link for book here.[enter link description here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.86278/page/n27/mode/2up)

Comment: Oh i see, thank you.